# How to take the values from a selected row in Tkinter Listbox and delete from sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have a row of entries in a listbox in Tkinter, what I'm trying to do is click on a row in the listbox and then click the delete button and have this row of values deleted from the sqlite3 database.  Here is the part of my code that gets the selected row in the listbox

```
person = self.listbox1.curselection()
```

Later on, here is the part of my code that says delete from database "people" (which is the name of my table).

```
list=c.execute("DELETE FROM people WHERE name =?", (person,))
```

The problem is, I don't know what to put in this line, you can see what I tried to do, but I get "OperationalError: no such column: name"

Also, each row in the listbox contains name, age, phone number

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('phonebook1.db')
            c = conn.cursor()
            conn.execute('''
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people(name TEXT primary key,
            age TEXT, phone TEXT)''')
            c.execute("insert into people values (?, ?, ?)", (item, item2, item3))
            conn.commit()
```

Comment: I should also ask, is 'person' a tuple of the data that i fed into the listbox earlier? like (name, text, phone) or is name just one long string?  If it's one long string I'm guessing that's why it won't work?  I don't really know.

Comment: I gave you answer with full code on [How to delete a row from a listbox in TKinter and SQLite3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738499/how-to-delete-a-row-from-a-listbox-in-tkinter-and-sqlite3)

Answer (score 1):

I gave you answer with full code on [How to delete a row from a listbox in TKinter and SQLite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738499/how-to-delete-a-row-from-a-listbox-in-tkinter-and-sqlite3)

If you had problem with that code you should continue discussions rather than create a new question.

---

`"OperationalError: no such column: name"`

Probably you created table `people` without column `name` and now you have to delete `'phonebook1.db'` to recreate table `people` with column `name`

Or you have to use SQL query `ALTER TABLE ...` to add column `name` to existing table.

---

**EDIT:**

By the way:

Query `"DELETE FROM people WHERE name =?"` expect one element - name - not tuple `person`
Correct:

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM people WHERE name =?", (person[0]))
```

Query `"DELETE FROM ..."` return nothing so in code below you don't get list

```
list = c.execute("DELETE FROM ...")
```